# Consuming from the beginning of a kafka topic with Flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-flink, flink-streaming

**How do I make sure I always consume from the beginning of a Kafka topic with Flink?**

With the [Kafka 0.9.x consumer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer09.html) that is part of Flink 1.0.2, it appears that it's no longer Kafka but Flink to control the offset:

> Flink snapshots the offsets internally as part of its
>   distributed checkpoints. The offsets committed to Kafka / ZooKeeper
>   are only to bring the outside view of progress in sync with Flink's
>   view of the progress. That way, monitoring and other jobs can get a
>   view of how far the Flink Kafka consumer has consumed a topic.

This is how far I got, but my Flink program always starts where it left off, and doesn't return to the beginning as the configuration instructs it to:

```
val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.setProperty("group.id", "myflinkservice")
props.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")

val incomingData = env.addSource(
  new FlinkKafkaConsumer09[IncomingDataRecord](
    "my.topic.name",
    new IncomingDataSchema,
    props
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
consumer.setStartFromEarliest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get around this by specifying a random `group.id`:

```
val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.setProperty("group.id", s"myflinkservice_${UUID.randomUUID}")
props.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "smallest") // "smallest", not "earliest"
```

`auto.offset.reset` only works when there's no initial offset available in ZooKeeper.

Comment: That's what I have been doing :-) but it's not practical, as I loose the ability of specifying a group for my Kafka consumers. As per the docs that I've quoted in my question, Flink 1.0.2 apparently doesn't any longer rely on the offsets committed to zookeeper and keeps track of the offsets itself.

Comment: When the Kafka consumer starts and there is no offset available for the group, it'll start according to the offset reset strategy.
All the offset tracking Flink is doing applies only for the lifetime of a job (with the exception of savepoints). So once the job is stopped, we rely on ZK or the auto offset strategy.
What you are looking for is the ability to completely disable the offset committing (to ZK or the broker) so that Flink can never pick the offsets up. That's a feature currently not available in Flink's Kafka connector

Comment: Are you sure smallest is correct? I am getting this exception, but it works fine with earliest. org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value smallest for configuration auto.offset.reset: String must be one of: latest, earliest, none